# Seeking a OOP design review for generic typed class

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, class-design

I am implementing a operation helper class like:

```
class ComparisonHelper {
  
  public static Comparison<Long> lt(String key, long value) {
    return new Comparison<>(ComparisonOperator.LT, key, value);
  }
  
  public static Comparison<Integer> lt(String key, int value) {
    return new Comparison<>(ComparisonOperator.LT, key, value);
  }

  public static Comparison<Float> lt(String key, float value) {
    return new Comparison<>(ComparisonOperator.LT, key, value);
  }

  public static Comparison<Double> lt(String key, double value) {
    return new Comparison<>(ComparisonOperator.LT, key, value);
  }

// 4 more methods for each of ComparisonOperator.[LTE, GT, GTE]
// total 16 methods in the class
// LT - less than, GT - greater than, GTE - greater than equals, LTE - greater than equals
}
```

I am ending up with a lot of duplicate methods that only differ in small details. I want to offer a user of this class to be able to create comparisons like `ComparisonHelper.lt("key", 20)` or `ComparisonHelper.gte("key", 30.0)`. In future, I can support comparisons for say `Date` or any other generic type. How can I improve my design?

Comment: `public static <T> Comparison<T> lt(String key, T value) { ... }`. You can pass primitives to that method, though they will be boxed to their respective reference types. So, you could keep the primitive overloads in addition to the generic version, or just keep only the generic version if boxing of primitives is not a concern to you (personally, I'd say assume it's not a problem until you profile otherwise).

Comment: Note that if your `Comparison` class relies on the value being e.g., `Comparable`, then you can bound `T`. For example: `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`.

Comment: Or in short, your `Comparison` class and its constructor obviously do already contain the abstraction you want for you factory method. Use a similar declaration for your method.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redesign you class to be **OOP**, think of it as an object with methods. Avoid using **'er'** suffix in class name, it should be a noun not a verb under cover. As an object that has methods it should respond to a qeuestion: `isBiggerThan`, `isSmallerThan`, `isLonger` and of course we want to compare an object to another object, so method parameter of the method should be an object of the same type as the main one.

This class seems that needs to be extracted into an interface named `Comparable` for example. The object `Apple`, that will implement the interface will have method `isGreaterThan(Comparable comparable)` that can return a Boolean with the answer, or object that hold comparison result named `ComparisonResult`, or simply `Result`.
We can have also an abstract `Apple` if its needed, named `Fruit`.

In this example `lt(String key, long value)` its procedural thinking, this is why you have troubles to transform it in OOP, because it makes no sense as an object abstraction from real world. We don't have strings and longs in real world.